# Fourier series of the fractional part

Tags: fourier-series

What is the Fourier series for $\{a\}\{b\}$, i.e. the product of the fractional parts of $a$ and $b$. I know what the Fourier series looks like for a single value of either $a$ or $b$, but I want to know what it is when the two are multiplied together.

Comment: I'm not quite sure what a Fourier series for a function of two variables looks like, but what happens if you just multiply the two individual Fourier series together?

Comment: I get a complicated double series, which im not sure how to simplify.

Comment: What kind of simplification are you looking for? and do you have any reason to think the kind of simplification you are looking for actually exists?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If $0 \leq \{a\} < 1$ and $0 \leq \{b\} < 1$, then $0 \leq \{a\}\{b\} < 1$. So the Fourier series of the product would look just like the Fourier series of $\{c\}$ of some real number $c$.

Comment: But I need it to match up at the discontinuites of both a, and b

Comment: I think $\{a\}$ and $\{b\}$ are meant as real functions in the variables $a$ and $b$ respectively, not fixed numbers.

Comment: @WimC Just define $\{c\} = \{a\}\{b\}$, which is the fractional part of some real number $c$.